# How do I make WPF case-insensitive?

Tags: wpf, vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I dislike WPF's inability to interpret text in a case-insensitive way.

Are there any tools (i.e. VS plugins) out there that will take my VB .NET code and handle the case-sensitivity issues for me?

Edit: Now with examples.

Input:

```
<Dockpanel DockPanel.Dock="Bottom">
        <Label Content="(c) blahblah" HorizontalAlignment="Left"  Name="Label2" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Opacity=".75" Background="White" DockPanel.Dock="bottom"/>
    </DockPanel>
```

Output:

```
<DockPanel DockPanel.Dock="Bottom">
    <Label Content="(c) blahblah" HorizontalAlignment="Left"  Name="Label2" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Opacity=".75" Background="White" DockPanel.Dock="Bottom"/>
</DockPanel>
```

Comment: Can you provide some specific examples? Specifically, what do you mean by taking your VS.NET code and handle case-sensitivity?

Comment: -1, Poorly worded with no examples.

Comment: Personnally, I dislike VB.NET's inability to interpret text in a case-sensitive way... BTW, in your example the input and output are the same.

Comment: Actually, they are different. One example: "bottom" vs. "Bottom"

Answer (score 5):

This is kind of like trying to use C# without ; or XAML without angle brackets. Case sensitivity is an intrinsic part of the XAML language and the WPF Binding system. If your VB code is causing problems when you're using it with WPF turn Option Strict on and fix the inconsistent casing in your code.

Comment: Just because it's a part of the language doesn't mean it's not worth trying to fix.

Comment: That's true. So use the fix for VB by turning on Option Strict.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that WPF is the problem here.

If you need to validate data and remove case from the problem, then convert all your strings to Upper or Lower before comparing.

If you need to change the way that a TextBox functions in WPF, either create your own inherited TextBox and override the Text property or modify the setters in your bound properties to modify any value it receives such as

```
public string Name
{
  get { return this._name; }
  set 
  { 
     this._name = value.ToUpper(); 
     OnPropertyChanged("Name");
  }
}
```

Without more information about the problem, I am not sure what else to suggest.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure what you're trying to achieve, but I ran into case sensitivity issues when checking usernames. Our standard is SimpsonHJ, but some users would log into their machines as simpsonhj or SIMPSONHJ. So I made a variable that changes the username found to all uppercase

```
private string un = Environment.UserName.ToUpper();
```

Answer (score 0):

easy and simple 
If you have to compare two strings. 
One can be stored in list, string or is some variable, other string is inputted by user on text box.
Then simply use To Upper or To Lower 
These will convert the string first into upper or lower case just for compair_values.
Ex.

```
string s = "ram" ;
string p = "Ram" ;

if(s.ToUpper()==p.ToUpper())
 {
   Console.WriteLine("String matched");
   MessageBox.Show("String matched");
 }
else 
{
   Console.WriteLine("Not matched");
   MessageBox.Show("Not matched");
}
```

Try it, you will get your answer